# Possible to debug old solutions running in 2010 mode in a 2013 environment?

Tags: 2013, solution-package, debugging

I've got a SharePoint 2013 VM for development using Visual Studio 2013. I've deployed an "old" 2010 wsp containing a visual webpart for using it within site collections running **in 2010 mode** in my 2013 SharePoint.

Now I've got the "old" 2010 C# source code and I want to debug the webpart running in these 2010 mode site collections.

But I'm not able to build and deploy the 2010 solution with my Visual Studio 2013: I receive a lot of compiler warnings, saying that all references to Microsof.SharePoint.* and Microsoft.Office.Server.* cannot be resolved.

Is there a simple way to **just debug** 2010 solutions in a 2013 environment? Maybe using old pdb-files? I don't want to upgrade and rebuild the old projects, just debug them.

Comment: Have you made sure the SharePoint dll versions are supported on your environment?

Comment: Ahmm ... What do you mean exactly? Copying the 2010 dlls to the "stripped down" 14-hive of the 2013 environment? I haven't done something like that.

Comment: I mean are the SharePoint DLLs referred in your project present in the windows assembly folder or GAC_MSIL folder on your server? If not, have you tried referring to the 15.0.0.0 version of the DLLs instead since you are now on a SP2013 VM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Preface

As is described in my initial question I **just want to debug** custom SharePoint 2010 solutions running in 2010 mode on a SharePoint 2013 farm. This answer is not about changing and re-compiling 2010 code in a 2013 environment.

## Requirements

You need at least these artifacts to debug your 2010 solution:

- Source code of your solution
- The corresponding wsp-package
- The corresponding pdb-file for the wsp-package (in fact this is the most important bit; see next)

## Getting the pdb-files

The pdb-file is essential for debugging. (Definition see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899573/what-is-a-pdb-file) or [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_database)). This great blog article from John Robbins ["PDB Files: What Every Developer Must Know"](http://www.wintellect.com/blogs/jrobbins/pdb-files-what-every-developer-must-know) describes in detail how to get the right pdb-file using the `dumpbin /headers` command from the Visual Studio tools.

Unfortunately I didn't keep the pdb-file for my 2010 wsp-package I deployed to the 2013 farm. But fortunately I still have access to a SharePoint 2010 VM with Visual Studio 2010. Here is how I generated the needed pdb-file then:

1. Get the source code of your solution
2. Do a new, clean build and deploy the solution to the 2010 environment from Visual Studio so that a wsp-file is generated.
3. Grab the generated dll-file and wsp-package located under `\bin\Debug`.
4. Inspect the generated dll-file with `dumpbin /headers` to obtain the information about the needed pdb-file. (In my case I had to use the pdb-file located unter `\obj\Debug` **not** `\bin\Debug`.) Grab that pdb-file. Make sure the pdb-file was actually generated for the dll/wsp build before: **pdb, dll and wsp should have the same timestamp**.

## Deploying the solution to SharePoint 2013

Now copy the source code, the wsp-Package and the pdb-file to your 2013 environment.

1. Deploy the wsp-Package to your 2013 environment as usual using PowerShell / CA.
2. Copy the pdb-file to the **exact** location the `dumpbin /headers` command told you (see above). The [blog article](http://www.wintellect.com/blogs/jrobbins/pdb-files-what-every-developer-must-know) of John Robbins says that there are better places to store your pdb-file but copying it to the exact location did it for me.

## Debugging

1. Open the source code project in Visual Studio and **do not** upgrade the project to 2013.
2. Just attach to the IIS worker process(es). No need to build the code.

The symbols from the pdb-file should be loaded so that you can debug your solution. See `Debug > Windows > Module` from the menu while debugging to check if the pdb-file is loaded.

Now you should be able to debug your 2010 solution running in 2010 mode in a 2013 environment.

Answer (score 1):

There are few things you will have to change in order for your solution to be deployed on SharePoint 2013.

- Make sure that target framework for your solution is .Net Framework 3.5 (or above).
- Update SharePoint Product version to 15.0 so that all your files gets deployed to 15 Hive and not 14 hive.

[image]

Comment: So I have to build and deploy the code as a "15 solution" again to debug the already installed 2010 wsp file? Will the new 15 solution really run **in 2010 mode sites**? Please note: I don't want to upgrade the 2010 solution, just debug it running in 2010 mode on a 2013 farm.

Comment: @jcp in that case just make sure your solution is targeting the right framework.  You may have to update the reference to SharePoint assemblies in your solution.